# How to push a model checkpoint to Huggingface?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I finished training my model, and didn't know that I need to change the training args to have `push_to_hub=True`.

Is there any other way that I can upload my model to huggingface? I am using Google Colab notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use `model.push_to_hub()` after authenticating. See the page here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_sharing

**Authenticate**:

```
# via bash
huggingface-cli login
```

```
# via python & Jupyter
pip install huggingface_hub
from huggingface_hub import notebook_login
notebook_login()
```

**Upload the model**

```
model.push_to_hub('myhuggingfaceusername/nameofmyawesomemodel')
```